# Why are Stack Exchange websites, especially Stack Overflow, much too slow?

Tags: bug, performance, page-load

Stack Exchange websites like Stack Overflow are sometimes very slow. Why is that? I can hardly even enter the website.

Does anyone else have this problem too?

My "Current" status:

[image: network graph]

and sometimes It's first item is like:

[image]

Comment: This sounds more like a problem with your network than with Stack Exchange.

Comment: But my network has no problem with other websites.

Comment: If you run `tracrt stackoverflow.com` what are your results? Mine are 13 hops and 92ms on the last hop.

Comment: I used ping. It seems currently it loads better. 304ms
from iran. But recently most of the time it's very slow.

Comment: Define "slow" - how slow is slow? Have you ruled out your network? Your ISP? How have you done so?

Comment: Slow means when for example it takes 3 seconds to load other similar (in page size) websites it sometimes takes me few minutes to enter the website!

Comment: Is this the experience for others in your area? Minutes is far too long - this is not usual and is almost certainly limited to yourself and your network/ISP. Please add traceroute information. When loading a page, can you see _what_ is taking a long time (through the browser dev tools)?

Comment: I don't know whether it's other's problem or not. Maybe some facebook link which is filtered here is slowing it!

Comment: This has only recently started happening for me - since there is the new left panel

Comment: Is anyone seeing this since our move to Fastly?

Answer (score 6):

In order to help you, we're going to need to know what *precisely* is slow. It could be that your ISP isn't peered well with our CDN. We need to see where the requests are taking an inordinate amount of time.

The best way to do this is to open the developer tools console of your browser, look at the network performance area and take a shot:

[image]

Console output is also very important.

You can then [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) directly, or post here on meta (just update your question). As stated, there's not nearly enough information in your question for us to begin to answer it accurately.

Comment: FYI, OP added some screenshots. :)